# Angular JS Service Creation Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created this service. 
and using **enrollments.getProperty();**this statement to call this service but it's not working I'm new to angular-JS please let me know where I making the mistake.

```html
var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
helloAjaxApp.service('enrollments',  [ '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
 
 $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    var enrollments = null;
    enrollment();
    $scope.enrollment=function () {
      $http({
     url : 'enrollments',
        method : "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
       
     enrollments = response.data;
        alert("enrollments");
    });
    };
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return enrollments;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
         enrollments = value;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: where is you define module?

Comment: var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error ,its not hitting the server only

Answer (score 0):

> use angular.module()

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("helloAjaxApp")
        .service('enrollments', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            var enrollments = null;
            enrollment();
            $scope.enrollment = function () {
                $http({
                    url: 'enrollments',
                    method: "GET"
                }).then(function (response) {

                    enrollments = response.data;
                    alert("enrollments");
                });
            };
            return {
                getProperty: function () {
                    return enrollments;
                },
                setProperty: function (value) {
                    enrollments = value;
                }
            };
        }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has 2 ways of defining a service: `service` and `factory`.

here you can see the difference: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

The basic difference is that service is like a constructor, so you don't return an object from it but define the properties using `this` keyword:

```
this.getProperty = function () {
    return enrollments;
}
```

When using the factory method, is expects an object to be returned with the exposed properties/functions.

You are using the factory syntax, so just change the definition to use factory:

```
helloAjaxApp.factory('enrollments',  [ '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for a proper service structure like so:

```
var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

function EnrollmentService($scope, $http) {
    let _this = this;
    this.enrollments = null;
    this.getEnrollments = function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'enrollments',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            _this.enrollments = response.data;
            return _this.enrollments;
        })
    };

    this.setEnrollments = function(enrollments) {
        _this.enrollments = enrollments;
    }
}

helloAjaxApp.service('enrollments', ['$scope', '$http', EnrollmentService]);
```

Then, use the service anywhere else:

```
enrollmentService
    .getEnrollments()
    .then(function(enrollments) {
        // You can use the data here.
        console.log(enrollments);
    });
```

Comment: its not calling that service getEnrollments

Comment: I changed the method name to improve readability, getEnrollments is your getProperty.

Comment: i understand that but still not able to call that service, using following code   enrollmentService
  .getEnrollments()
  .then(function(enrollments) {
      You can use the data here.
    console.log(enrollments);
 });  i have usd this also      enrollmentService
  .getEnrollments()
  .then(function() {
      You can use the data here.
    
 });

Answer (score 0):

**The controller code**

*LoginService* is service name you have to pass as a parameter to controller

```
var loginModule = angular.module('LoginModule',[]);
loginModule.controller('logincontroller', ['$rootScope','$scope','$http','$window','$cookieStore',
                                                    'LoginService',logincontrollerFun ]);

function logincontrollerFun($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window,$cookieStore, LoginService,RememberService) {



    $scope.loginTest = function() {

        LoginService.UserStatus($scope, function(resp) {
            console.log("response of login controller ::: ", resp);
            ///write ur code

        });
    }
}
```

**service code**

```
    var loginModule = angular.module('LoginModule')
loginModule.factory("LoginService",[ '$http', LoginServiceFun ])

    function LoginServiceFun($http) {
        function UserStatus($scope,callback){

              var targetRequestPath='./url';
              var targetRequestParamsREQ={'email':$scope.email,'password':$scope.passWord};
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: targetRequestPath,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: targetRequestParamsREQ
            }).then(function (response){
                console.log('Response Data : ', response.data);
                callback( response.data );
            })
        }
        return {
            UserStatus:UserStatus
            }

        }
```